# Zabbix. SQL или API запрос : Вывести все хосты с определенным значением ITEM (Zabbix 2.4)

Tags: sql, api, zabbix

Подскажите как вывести все хосты у которых значение определенного ITEM больше 50.

Ситуация ситуация такая , есть некоторый template, который привязан к 1000 хостов. В этом темплейте есть item. Мне необходимо получить список хостов у которых последнее значение этого item больше 50. 
Попробовал сделать через API, как посоветовали на форуме Zabbix . Через API получил template ID,  и item ID. А вот что делать дальше с этим не понятно.
Вот то что у меня получилось:

```
#DES 3200 CPU get script
echo "D-Link DES 3200 CPU util Get Script"

zbxUser=''
zbxPass=''
zbxAPI='http://localhost/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php'

DATA=`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S`
# Get auth token from zabbix
curlOutput=`curl -sS -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d "{\"params\": {\"password\": \"$zbxPass\", \"user\": \"$zbxUser\"}, \"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\", \"method\": \"user.login\", \"id\": 0}" $zbxAPI`
authToken=`echo $curlOutput | sed -n 's/.*result":"\(.*\)",.*/\1/p'`

# Get all monitored and problem state triggers
curlData="{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"template.get\", \"params\": {\"search\":{\"name\":\"D-Link DES3200\"}},\"output\":[\"template.id\"], \"auth\":\"$authToken\", \"id\": 1}"
curlOutput=`curl -sS -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d "$curlData" $zbxAPI`
echo "$curlOutput" > $DATA.log
TEMPLATE=`cat $DATA.log| sed "s/,/,\n/g;s/}/\n/g" | grep "templateid" | sed s/[^0-9]//g`
echo "Template ID : $TEMPLATE"
rm $DATA.log

#Get Item ID
curlData2="{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"item.get\", \"params\": {\"templateids\":\"$TEMPLATE\",\"search\":{\"name\":\"CPU 5 min\"},\"searchWildcardsEnabled\":1,\"selectHosts\":[\"host\"]},\"output\":[\"lastvalue\"], \"auth\":\"$authToken\", \"id\": 2}"
curlOutput2=`curl -sS -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d "$curlData2" $zbxAPI`
echo "$curlOutput2" > $DATA_2.log
#echo $curlOutput2
ITEMID=`cat $DATA_2.log| sed "s/,/,\n/g;s/}/\n/g" | grep itemid | sed s/[^0-9]//g`

echo "Item ID : $ITEMID"
rm $DATA_2.log

#Get host id
curlData3="{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"host.get\",\"params\": {\"monitored_hosts\":1}, \"output\":[\"hostid\"],\"filter\":{\"itemids\":\"$ITEMID\"}, \"auth\":\"$authToken\", \"id\": 3}"
curlOutput3=`curl -sS -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d "$curlData3" $zbxAPI`
echo "$curlOutput3" > $DATA_3.log
echo $curlOutput3 | sed "s/,/,\n/g;s/}/\n/g" | grep hostid | grep -v "proxy_hostid"
```

Подскажите , может через SQL запрос проще? Как будет выглядеть такой запрос?

Пример вывода 
   Template ID : 12223 
   Item ID : 585027
   "result":[{"hostid":"10084", 
   {"hostid":"10117",
   {"hostid":"10119",
   {"hostid":"10157",
   {"hostid":"10161",
   {"hostid":"10162",
   {"hostid":"10163",
   {"hostid":"10164",
   {"hostid":"10165",
   {"hostid":"10166",
   {"hostid":"10451",

Comment: 1. лезть в SQL, наверное, плохая идея, т.к. где гарантия, что структура базы не поменяется в следующей версии Zabbix?
2. API лучше использовать, т.к. оно более стабильное, чем п.1
3. возьмите лучше Python. Если API действительно выдает JSON, то его проще обработать скриптовыми языками, чем через консоль sed'ить
4. чтоб совсем наверняка помочь - приведите, пожалуйста, пример вывода...

Comment: Спасибо за отклик , пример добавил в вопрос.
Всего hostid получается 1297 - это количество устройств в мониторинге. При этом я однозначно знаю что не ко всем устройствам привязан заданный item

Comment: Лучше на pastebin выложите, т.к. SO "съел" часть вывода

Comment: Выложил на pastebin 
http://pastebin.com/gN2kCiJF
http://pastebin.com/G6aiLvgT

Comment: я немного не это имел в виду - я хотел вывод именно Заббикса. Потому что если он в виде JSON, то Вы его просто подгружаете как JSON массив в Python скрипт и далее можно его в нем просто обработать. Пример http://pythonicway.com/education/basics/17-python-json-parse
Далее Вы просто пробегаетесь уже по массиву, который получился из JSON строки и выбираете элементы с "hostid" > 50